# Regex : replace a phrase only if NOT preceded by a word

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to replace some phrase ("my term") in text files with perl command line. Those files are divided in section, like this :

```
section1
my term
nothing abc

section2
some text
my term
another text

section3
some text
my term

section4
some text
my term
```

Some sections may not exist. What I want to achieve is replace "my term" by "some other term", but only if it is in section1. I tried some lookahead and lookbehinds syntax, but wasn't able to find a working solution (https://regex101.com/r/mfqay6/1)

For example, if I delete section 1, the following code match, whereas I don't want it :

```
(?!section2).*(my term)
```

Any help there ?

Comment: Is that what you want: https://regex101.com/r/mfqay6/2

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Was a bit lost, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple one liner:

```
perl  -ane 's/my term/some other term/ if(/section1/ ... /section/);print' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
section1
some other term
nothing abc

section2
some text
my term
another text

section3
some text
my term

section4
some text
my term
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex:

```
((?:section1)(?:(?!my term)(?!^\s*$)[\d\D])+)(my term)

(                //start group 1
  (?:            //start non-capturing group (keeps it organized)
     section1    //match section1
  )              //end non-capturing group
  (?:            //start another non-capturing group
     (?!         //start negative lookahead
        my term  //don't match "my term"
     )           //end negative lookahead
     (?!         //start negative lookahead
        ^\s*$    //don't match an empty line
     )           //end negative lookahead
     [\d\D]      //match any character
  )+             //repeat this non-capturing group 1 or more times
)                //end group 1
(my term)        //match "my term" in group 2
```

And here is what to replace with:

```
$1my other term

$1            //everything up to "my term", including newline characters
my other term //the other term
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, though the one-liner perl command was what I needed.